# g++ unable to link OpenAL Libraries

Tags: c++, linux, g++, openal

I have trouble compiling the following code

```
#include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alc.h>

#include <iostream>


int checkEnumerationSupport() {

    ALboolean enumeration;

    enumeration = alcIsExtensionPresent(NULL, "ALC_ENUMERATION_EXT");

    if (enumeration == AL_FALSE) {
        // enumeration not supported
        std::cout << "enumerating devices NOT supported\n";
    } else {
        // enumeration supported
        std::cout << "enumerating devices supported\n";
    };

    return 0;

}


int main() {

    checkEnumerationSupport();

}
```

using the command below.

```
g++ test.cpp -o test
```

I get the following message:

```
/tmp/ccEN7YAp.o: In function `checkEnumerationSupport()':
test.cpp:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `alcIsExtensionPresent'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Realising the libraries weren't linked correctly, I tried changing the g++ line to

```
g++ -L/usr/lib/ test.cpp -o test -lal -lalc
```

giving me the following message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lal
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lalc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tested it on **Linux Mint 17.2** and **Ubuntu 14.04**.

Does anyone know how to compile the code correctly?

Comment: Can you see the library files in /usr/lib/?

Comment: And have you tried with `-lopenal` instead of `-lal` and `-lalc`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is to link to the OpenAL library using `-lopenal` instead of `-lal` and `-lalc`